# Average values with specific parameters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets I have data in the range **`Sheet3!A:C`** as pictured below:

[image: Sample Sheet3 data]

I would like to average the values in   **`"Volume (ml)"`** (range **`Sheet3!C:C`**), by unique combination of **`"ID Primary"`** and **`"Date"`**.

Below is an example of my expected output based on the sample data above.

[image: Example desired results]

Comment: averageifs if that's available on google

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: This question contains more than 50% of useless info (Every info on Sheet1 and Sheet3 is not referred to in the rest of the question).   Please provide a [mre], and read: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which says: "Include **just enough** code to allow others to reproduce the problem", and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) (In this case the picture are useless for the problem, and could have been posted as TEXT.(

Comment: What is the formula on Sheet 3? What is the result that you are expecting on sheet 3?

Comment: `QUERY()` should work with `AVERAGE()`.

Comment: @Harun24hr thank you sir, today i used formula query and unique in sheet 3 (column A and B). My formula is : =QUERY(UNIQUE(Sheet13!A2:B); "SELECT * WHERE Col1 is not null"; 0), then in column 3 i used formula averageifs : =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(Sheet13!C2:C; Sheet13!A2:A; A2; Sheet13!B2:B;B2);"")). Is that true sir?

Comment: Please confirm if your dates are always integers, i.e. dates only or dates and times (regardless how they are displayed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternate Formula:

Based on your given data, this formula uses `Query` and `Substitute` to convert the volume data from comma-separated to period-separated decimal and display the average volume per ID and Date

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!A:B, IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!C:C, ",", ".")))}, "SELECT Col1, Col2, AVG(Col3) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1, Col2 LABEL AVG(Col3) 'Average Volume (mL)'",1)), 1, False)
```

### Result:

[image]

Note: Please adjust the Sheet name accordingly that suits your google sheets

### References:

[Query Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

[Substitute](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en&sjid=4597126920758649726-AP)

Answer (score 1):

## If `date` is an Integer

```
=QUERY(Sheet3!A:C, 
  "Select A, B, AVG(C)
   where A is not Null 
   Group by A, B", 1)
```

Equivalent formula adapted for locales using comma as decimal separator:

```
=QUERY(Sheet3!A:C;
  "Select A, B, AVG(C) 
   where A is not Null 
   Group by A, B"; 1)
```

## If `date` includes Times

Use ARRAYFORMULA and INT to first convert the datetime values to dates.

```
=QUERY(
  {Sheet3!A:A, ARRAYFORMULA(
    {Sheet3!B1;INT(Sheet3!B2:B)}),
   Sheet3!C:C}, 
  "Select Col1, Col2, AVG(Col3)
   where Col1 is not Null 
   Group by Col1, Col2", 1)
```

Equivalent formula adapted for locales using comma as decimal separator:

```
=QUERY(
  {Sheet3!A:A\ ARRAYFORMULA(
    {Sheet3!B1;INT(Sheet3!B2:B)})\
   Sheet3!C:C}; 
  "Select Col1, Col2, AVG(Col3)
   where Col1 is not Null 
   Group by Col1, Col2"; 1)
```